# Touble web scraping streaming sites

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to make a web scraper using Python and I'm facing one issue. Every streaming site I try to inspect doesnt let me inspect it's html code when i'm on the episodes page. It sends me back to the home page whenever I open Element Inspector. Any help?

I'm new to web scraping so I don't know another way of doing this

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# THIS PROJECT IS JUST TO SCRAPE ZORO.TO AND DOWNLOAD ANIME USING IT

# Make a request and get the return the HTML content of a webpage
def getWebpage(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    return BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib') 

# Search the title and get it's Page Url
def getWatchUrl(titleName):
    keyword = ""

    # Transform the Anime title into a Url as on the website
    for word in titleName.split(sep=" "):
        keyword += '+' + word 
    keyword = keyword[1:]

    SearchURL = f'https://zoro.to/search?keyword={keyword}'

    # Get the HTML contents of the website
    try:
        soup = getWebpage(SearchURL)

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Unexpected Error {e}. Please try again!")
        return None

    # Seperate the useful content (Anime title and Links) 
    try:    
        titles = soup.findAll('div', {'class' : 'film-poster'},  limit=None)

    except:
        print(e)
        print("Couldn't Find title. Check spellings and please try again!")
        return None

    # Search the content for Anime title and extract it's link
    for title in titles:
        for content in title:
            try:
                if titleName in content.get('title').lower():
                    path = content.get('href').replace('?ref=search', '')
                    watchURL = f'https://zoro.to/watch{path}'
                    return watchURL

            except:
                continue
    
    print("Couldn't Find title. Check spellings and please try again!")
    return None

# Get the direct download links from the Web page
def getDownloadUrl(watchUrl):
    try:
        soup = getWebpage(watchUrl)
        print(soup.prettify())

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Unexpected Error {e}. Please try again!")
        return None
    
def main():
    animeName = input("Enter Anime Name: ").lower()
    watchURL = getWatchUrl(animeName)
    if watchURL is not None: getDownloadUrl(watchURL)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: you can always view the page source - if you wanted to see the element that you are talking about outside of the inspect element tab.

Comment: As I mentioned in the body, I can't get the links from the website because it redirects me back to the home page when i open Inspect Element -@AndrewRyan

Comment: you could always do `view-source:https://zoro.to/watch/bleach-thousand-year-blood-war-arc-15665?ep=94563` to see the elements

Comment: I have no problem getting the links, however, if you try to **watch** an episode without logging in - then it will redirect you back. So I think the issue you are having - relates to the login in some way.

Comment: @ScottC that may not be the case (it may be related to ads on the site) with an ad blocker you can watch the episodes without logging in.

Comment: okay what @AndrewRyan suggested worked, but im facing a new problem now. Where i should ideally be getting episode numbers and lists, im getting ```javascript:;```. Any help with that?

Comment: @MythicalPhantom When I use firefox, I can view the page without redirecting me to the home page. However, I cant open dev tools. `Beautiful soup` is fine, when you want to scrape html, but you need to run javascript (thats why you got `javascript:;`). If you just want to see links, I recommend you to use [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/). Also use [mitmproxy web](https://mitmproxy.org/) to see traffic how javascript is finding path to video. I am not sure, but I think you wont find video in good format such as mp4.